# Reinitialize Sencha Touch app without performing a page reload

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

In some cases I need to reinitialize my Sencha Touch app. Till now I just used `location.reload()` to do this. However this is really bad for the user experience as the whole HTML page, JS and CSS will be reloaded, too.

So I'm looking for an easy and clean way to reset and reinitialize my app without reloading the whole page.

I tried to do something like `Ext.Viewport.removeAll(true, true)` to remove all view components from the viewport. But this results in some errors, when you masked the viewport before or if you showed some dialogs before. Sencha keeps some references to objects created while masking the view or showing a dialog, that won't be present any more after removing all components from the viewport:

```
Ext.Msg.alert()
Ext.Viewport.removeAll(true, true)
Ext.Msg.alert() // => will raise `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null`
```

How do you reinitialize your app without reloading the whole page? Is there any way to do it "the nice" way?

Comment: if you removed everything from the page, how would this be different from a reload to the user?

Comment: @dbrin It's for better user experience (in my case). I'm also looking for a way to init my app without reloading the page.

Comment: @mikrobi did you find any solution to your issue? How to reload Ext application without location.reload() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can relaunch the app by calling the launch function of you application. 
Suppose you application name is my_app, you can relaunch the app using:- 
my_app.app.launch()

Comment: I tried and failed (in 2.4.1). Call `my_app.app.launch()` would not trigger others launch function in profiles.